# Record level sharing for external objects

Tags: lightning-connect, externalobjects

As per the docs, record sharing is not available on External object. Does that means that all users will be able to see all external object records? (as they are searchable)

For example, let say you have Account and related orders (external object) records. Now, the user will have defined access to account records. However, will they be able to access all order records irrespective of their access to Account records?

Is there is way to configure record level access for records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 17SEP19, [record level access](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_connect_considerations_compatibility.htm&type=5) is not configurable for External Objects.

Record access ("all or nothing") is provided via Object Permissions at the Profile level.

For example, given External Object `alpha__x` a Profile could be configured to have "Read" access... or no visibility at all, depending on your business requirements.

Comment: That means, anyone can search record and view it. Irrespective of whether he should see it or not.

Comment: Record-level sharing aside, if an Individual should NOT see External Object records, simply remove their Profile access. Their global search won't turn up any results. All or nothing.

Comment: thought the same. Salesforce should provide some feature to control record level security for external objects.

Comment: FYI, just edited my answer to link to SF docs clearly calling out the limitations for External Objects.

Comment: appreciate your answer and link. I did checked that and that's why my question begins with "As per the docs". However, just wanted to cross check with community on the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [restriction rules on external objects](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_restriction_rule_create.htm&type=5) since end of 2022. To me they seem worthless though. You can only create 2 rules (5 for higher tier orgs) and you cannot have a rule match a field on User vs. a field on extObj__x.

You can only set specific values for one field on each object (e.g. User.RoleId = 'APAC18digits' can view extObj__x.Region__c = 'APAC').

With only 2 rules allowed this kind of mapping yields no use cases to me.